# Date calculation with PHPExcel library

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a  php script that have to parse an excel file with some date and time to import in my mysql database

**Screen of the xlsx file :**
[image]

**I'm using the PHPExcel library to read the file**

- When I get the cell value with **getValue()** method, it returns the formula **=J4+"01:00:00"** as showed in the excel formula field. **Ok normal**
- When I use the the **getCalculatedValue()** method, it returns **"#VALUE!"**. As excell / Libreoffice don't have any problem to calculate the formulas, I have no idea why the PHPExcel library is not able to calculate this quite simple formulas.

Do anyone had the same issue and know a trick to fix this issue ? Or do I realy have to tell users not use any formulas fort date fields type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the PHPExcel support platform.
The only way to manage this kind of formulase (date operation) is to replace my actual  formulas by something like **=J4+(1/24)**

Source : [PhpExcel support plateform](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/19958)